# Merging Data Frames in R - Text Analysis

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I'm working on doing some text analysis of the 20 Newsgroups Data set, and part of it relies on classifying the different articles based on the words in said articles. What I've currently been able to do is parse an individual article, and then compile statistics about it. I can do this individually per article, but combining the articles seems to be my downfall.

What I'm looking to be able to do, in R is the following:

Take two (ideally any number) dataframes of the frequency of the parsed and stemmed words, and merge them together to show the frequency of words in both articles as one data frame. I would like to be able to do this without combining the articles into a single larger document.

Take this dataframe and sort it by the top frequency, only displaying the top 50.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you're looking for `merge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not provide any example data, I just guess that your data are in a form like this:

```
doc1 <- data.frame( word = LETTERS[sample(26, 10)], freq = sample(100, 10) )
doc2 <- data.frame( word = LETTERS[sample(26, 10)], freq = sample(100, 10) )
```

Have a look at `? merge`. It does what you probably want:

```
merge( doc1, doc2, by = "word", all=TRUE, suffixes=c(".doc1", ".doc2") )
```

Comment: What does the "suffixes" part do? Also, any advice for the sorting? Any time I look this up, I follow the instructions, and the "order" function gives off errors. IF i were to order it by frequency, highest first, I know I'd have to put descending=T, but other than that, I don't know how to use "order"

Comment: Try it without suffixes and compare the colnames. Or have a look at `merge`'s documentation. Concerning the order of rows, you can `mdf <- merge(...); mdf[ order(mdf$freq.doc1, mdf$freq.doc2), ]`